# AWS CDK how to delete Custom::CrossRegionExportWriter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am having trouble deploying my stack - I am getting the following error:

```
Custom::CrossRegionExportWriter | ExportsWriteruswest1086A087133A0F94D
Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: ParameterAlreadyExists: The parameter already exists. To overwrite this value, set the overwrite o
ption in the request to true.
```

and I cannot find this resource from the console to delete it in the first place!
any idea where this resource is created and how can I delete it?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? It is a custom resource responsible for cross-region cross-stack references. The cause of the failure is in the error message, should be straightforward to fix.

Comment: @gshpychka, the question says how to delete it, it's not asking if this should be deleted or not, user might be doing something else

Comment: I understand, I am saying this is an XY problem - you do not want to delete this resource. To disable cross-region references, set the `crossRegionReferences` prop of the Stack to `false`, this will delete the resource.

Comment: yes I do, I need to delete it because I simply like to learn how to delete it - 
you can leave a comment saying "I don't know how to delete it, but consider not doing it because xyz"
and instead you voted down the question incorrectly - the question explicitly states "HOW TO DELETE"

Comment: Nice, I hope my comments clarified it for you

Comment: thank you for your comment, but it's not what I am asking for

Comment: How so? I explained how to remove it.

Comment: Your explanation is incorrect, I have asked how to delete it from the console which I have already figured out.

Comment: It is impossible to delete from the console, as it's a Custom Resource - it only exists in the template, it does not exist in the console. If you just delete the lambda, that will break things.

Comment: turns out the issue was being reported because a parameter store value was created in a different region so deleting that fixed the issue.

Comment: Sure, but the question wasn't how to fix the issue, it was how to remove the custom resource (which is what made this question an XY problem)

Comment: deleting the resource fixed my issue, thanks

Comment: @gshpychka I am not sure what are is your goal with engaging with this question, not only you haven't been helpful but are being childish

Comment: I'm sorry you got that impression, my goal was to guide you towards a better understanding of the issue. Your question asks how to remove the `Custom::CrossRegionExportWriter` custom resource. I have explained that this does not make sense, and the only way to remove it is to disable your cross-region references. I have tried explaining that you do not need to remove the custom resource to solve your issue (you have to remove the SSM parameter as you've discovered)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter this issue, and are deploying your stack using CDK, check all SSM parameters for all the regions and make sure to delete the parameter that is used for cross region export. this was my issue and it fixed it.

Comment: This would not delete the custom resource, just the SSM parameter.